# height: 100% - not 100%?

Tags: html, css, footer

There's a ton of questions about 100% height elements. There's also a ton of questions about how to keep footers down. Well, this is yet another one...

I've been building a site and I have problems with positioning my footer and having 100% height elements on the page. [My page looks currently like this.](http://mikko.peltoset.fi/rwd/)

I've tried almost everything I could possibly have found but nothing seems to work. If you look at the CSS code, do you find something that breaks the footer positioning and the height settings?

Comment: for the footer, use `position: fixed;`, not `absolute`

Comment: It's not supposed to be fixed...

Answer (score 2):

Check out [The css sticky footer](http://www.cssstickyfooter.com/)

You want your HTML To resemble this:

```
<div id="wrap">

    <div id="main">

    </div>

</div>

<div id="footer">

</div>
```

So, in your example (your website) you would want the `footer` to be outside of the `container`. From here you can simply check the `CSS` on the link provided above and your footer will stick to the bottom of the page while your DIV expands full height.

Comment: @the downvoter - this works perfectly, I use it on my sites.

Answer (score -1):

```
#contentWrapper{
 padding: 0;
 margin-left: 230px;
 height: 100%;
 background-color: #FFFFFF;
 overflow: auto; /*I added this*/
}

#grass {
 background: url("../images/layout/grass.png") repeat-x;
 width: 100%;
 bottom: 59px;
 height: 248px;
 position: fixed; /*Change absolute to fiexed*/
}
```